# results.map is not a function

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, axios

I am close to displaying my axios response results to a table but i keep getting the error. Still learning React. See the error below [image]

```
  Below is the code making API call

  const listJobs = () =>{
   axios.get( `${process.env.REACT_APP_API}/search-projects`,
    {params: {category
     }
    })
 .then(response => {
  console.log('LOG SUCCESS --', response.data);
  const results = response.data;
 setValues({...values, results: results});
  console.log('My State Data', results);


  })

 }
```

This is to display the data on the table

const { results } = values;

```
{ results.map(({id, title, description, budget}, index ) => {
              return (
                <tr key={id}>
                  <td>{id}</td>
                  <td>{title}</td>
                  <td>{description}</td>
                  <td>{budget}</td>
                </tr>
              );
    })}
```

Comment: Please, include full component code or better create runnable example using https://codesandbox.io/dashboard

Comment: Do you get the `LOG SUCCESS --` output in the console? Does `values` include the key/property `results` on first render?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the issue here is that, until your async axios call returns, `results` will be `undefined`, and so on the first few attempts to render your component, it is trying to call `.map()` on `undefinded` which won't work.

You could add some kind of guard in your jsx like:

```
{ results && results.map(...) }
```

Or initialize your `results` to an empty array at first, and reassign to the results of your axios call once that resolves.

Answer (score 1):

Axios makes an asynchronous request: you need to call it from useEffect hook (or componentDidMount) like so:

```
useEffect(() => {
  axios.get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API}/search-projects`).then(res => console.log(res))
})
```

Other problem is you aren't checking if the request finished and the state is updated

```
{
  results &&
    results.map(({ id, title, description, budget }, index) => {
      return (
        <tr key={id}>
          <td>{id}</td>
          <td>{title}</td>
          <td>{description}</td>
          <td>{budget}</td>
        </tr>
      )
    })
}
```

And finally, the request must be an array to use Array.prototype.map() [function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Answer (score 0):

```
const results = [];
if( Array.isArray( response.data ) ){
      setValues({...values, results: results});
};
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [answer]. Code-only answers might not be very helpful to OP or future viewers of this answer. Good answers include some explanation of _why_ this answer works and _what the OP got wrong_